# Making Android not clip the view while animating (simple flip-clock-like widget)

Tags: android, view, android-animation, clipping

I'm implementing a simple flip-clock / counter / ticker widget which will consist of several instances of a following "digit" widget:

[image]

It's a digit placed on top of a background image. The digit is supposed to animate every second by sliding up and revealing next digit. During the animation both digits should stay "within" the background's boundary.

I'm trying to achieve this behavior by having a `TextView` with 2 lines - one digit per line - and animating this `TextView`'s position upwards, until the next digit is fully visible. And then I will reset `TextView`s position and replace both digits at the same time, so that it's impossible to notice. Then I will repeat the process and make it look like the animation never ends.

Here you can see an intermediate state of the animation, when part of zero and part of nine is visible. I "mocked" it in the Graphical Layout editor of Eclipse, by setting the `layout_marginTop` property to a negative value.

[image]

Here's the layout file (the mentioned attribute is normally not there).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_countdown_normal_grey"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_countdown_digit"
            style="@style/TextView.CountdownDigit"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:text="0\n9" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried two solutions. By using `ViewPropertyAnimator` on either `translateY` or `y`, I get a smooth animation, but the original clipping of the `TextView` does not change during animation, so in effect the second digit is never visible. As you can see, I tried `clipChildren` property, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

My second approach was to use `ValueAnimator` with a custom `Evaluator`, which modifies the `topMargin` of `LayoutParams` on the `TextView`. It works, but the animation is very choppy even on high-end devices.

So my question is, **how to avoid view clipping during animation and make so in an efficient way? Is there a better approach?**

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution in which I use a ScrollView instead. My layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview_countdown_digit"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_countdown_normal_grey"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_countdown_digit1"
        style="@style/TextView.CountdownDigit"
        android:text="0\n9" />

</ScrollView>
```

I animate using `ObjectAnimator` by `scrollY` property. Works well so far.

I also tried having 2 `TextViews` intsead of one (in my initial layout), but it did not change the fact of clipping.